# RHQ - JMX plugin - Update attribute value

Tags: jboss7.x, jmx, mbeans, rhq

I'm using RHQ JMX plugin to get operations and attributes of one custom Mbean.
It is working but I would like to add the possibility to update an attribute value and I can't use the setter function to update it as it's not recognized as an operation.

How can I update my plugin to add this possibility ?

Comment: Have you implemented your own plugin? In this case, in the resource type describing your MBean you could add something like this `<resource-configuration><c:simple-property name="MyAttributeName" type="integer"/></resource-configuration>`

Comment: @tsegismont Yes, I' trying to implement my own plugin. Perfect, it's exactly that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing your own plugin, you can declare the bean attribute as a:

- measurement, to get history of values
- resource configuration property, to easily update the value from RHQ

Declaring an int MBean attribue in resource configuration works as follow:

```
<resource-configuration>
    <c:simple-property name="MyAttributeName" type="integer"/>
</resource-configuration>
```